# How do I get the my timer to display the right number format using NSDateComponentFormatter

Tags: xcode, swift

I've been trying to get my StopWatch to display the time in the following format
00h:00m:00s (suffixes are optional) using the `NSDateComponentFormatter()`

But I get is a continuous column of 0s.... any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

```
func timerResults(){
    ++stopWatchCounter


    let formatter = NSDateComponentsFormatter()
    formatter.unitsStyle = .Abbreviated
    formatter.allowedUnits = .CalendarUnitSecond | .CalendarUnitMinute | .CalendarUnitHour

    let counterComponents = NSDateComponents()
        counterComponents.hour = 00
        counterComponents.minute = 00
        counterComponents.second = 00

    if let stopwatch = formatter.stringFromDateComponents(counterComponents){

  //  stopWatch.text = "\(stopwatch)"
      stopWatch.text = "\(stopWatchCounter)"

            println(stopwatch)

    }}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thats not possible using NSDateComponentsFormatter(). If you use .Positional you would get something like this 1:01:01. If you use .Short would be like this "1 hr, 1 min, 1 sec". You can use String(format:) and create your own format as a NStimeInterval extension as follow:

```
extension NSTimeInterval {
    var time:String {
        return String(format:"%02dh:%02dm:%02ds", Int((self/3600.0)%100),Int((self/60.0)%60), Int((self) % 60 ))
    }
}

(359999.0).time    // "99h:59m:59s"
```